# Excel enter formula into cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function bd()

    Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").value=1

End Function
```

This is my function. 
Why is it that when i enter `=bd()` into any cell in sheet1, the data in A1 does not change to 1? I do not want to use the button to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

**Why it does not work:**

If you're calling your function from an Excel formula, your function becomes a User-Defined-Function (=UDF).

UDF have to follow special rules - the main one being that it cannot by any means change anything in Excel - it shall only return a value! Your function clearly violates this rules.

(For reference: the other main restriction is that it shall also not access any data outside the parameters that were passed to it when calling the function. Thus, you cannot use `MyUDF=Range("A1").Value` - but only something like `MyUDF=rngParam1.Value*2`!

**Alternative approach:**

If you want to change the worksheet but don't want to use a button, you need to think of some kind of trigger event. Look at the possible Worksheet and workbook events - you'll find a list of events [here](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/event.htm) - and detailed instruction how to use them [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx).

For instance, you could use the `Activate` of Sheet1. For this place this code in the Sheet1 code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Range("A1").Value = 1
End Sub
```

Now every time that sheet1 gets activated, A1 will be reset!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

**Copy this code on your 'Thisworkbook' on vba**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "bd()" Then
Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 1
End If
End Sub
```

---

*Now if you enter 'bd()' (without Quotes)  on cell A1 on Any Sheet and press enter the cell A1 of Sheet one will Change to 1*

**OR**

**Copy this code on your 'Thisworkbook' on vba**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "bd()" Then
Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 1
End If
End Sub
```

---

*Now if you enter 'bd()' (without Quotes) on cell A1 on  Sheet one and press enter the cell A1 of Sheet one will Auto Change to 1*

**Hope this works**